# How to show a progress bar, when using ExecutorService's awaitTermination method?

Tags: android, concurrency, executorservice, android-progressbar

I am building an app, which scrapes prices from several webpages, and then displays the result, after all tasks are completed. Everything works fine, except that I am struggling to add a progress bar.

Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. After pressing a button the program runs 2 tasks: the first one sleeps 3 seconds, the second one - 7 seconds. When all is done, toastmessages from each task are displayed.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button button;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

            executorService.submit(new Task1());
            executorService.submit(new Task2());

            executorService.shutdown();

            try {
                executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });



}

private class Task1 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Log.d("task1", "run: ");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "task1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

private class Task2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d("task2", "run: ");
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "task2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

As I understand the problem is that all threads are blocked when using awaitTermination method, including UI thread, and therefore Task results appear only after all tasks are completed.

Is there a way to wait until all tasks are completed, while still displaying a progress bar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right about `awaitTermination`. But it blocks only main thread, others are not touched with it.

One way to solve your problem is to define active task counter. Every time you run task, it increases. Every time task ends (including fail) counter decreases.

And of course you should remove `awaitTermination` method. In Android (and mostly in all UI related frameworks) you should not block UI thread.

Pseudo code of my proposition:

```
Button button;
ProgressBar progressBar;
int activeTaskCounter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

            executorService.submit(new Task1());
            executorService.submit(new Task2());
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    });
}

private void increaseActiveCounter() {
    activeTaskCounter += 1;
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void decreaseActiveCounter() {
    activeTaskCounter -= 1;
    if (activeTaskCounter == 0) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private class Task1 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // It's lambda here, but you can use anonymous class. It's up to you
        runOnUiThread(() -> increaseCounter());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Log.d("task1", "run: ");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            runOnUiThread(() -> decreaseActiveCounter());
        }
       
    }
}

private class Task2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(() -> increaseCounter());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            Log.d("task2", "run: ");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            runOnUiThread(() -> decreaseActiveCounter());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work in the example provided. Is there any way to keep awaitTermination functionality, while still showing a progressBar? The reason I used await termination, was to wait until all the necessary data is loaded, and only then display in the UI.

Comment: When activeTaskCoubter becomes zero, you can show your data, because it is loaded. It is the same as awaitTermination, but asynchronous.